# What was Pradip Burman's effort on Environment Day 2018?

Tags: communication

I am wondering today, how many people are aware about Environment Day and how they deal with it. How people come together to solve this issue.

Comment: This question may be better for [Sustainability.SE], but it also needs improvement: Please add links explanaining who PD and what ED is, and have your question text match your title (it's now 2 completely different questions). And people may vote to close this as 'too broad' if you ask how people deal with it.

Comment: This is both unclear and seemingly off-topic. It reads sort of like it's intended to promote the initiative in question; what does this question have to do with community building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This year on Environment Day, Pradip Burman announced the launch of an environmental initiative. This is Project Sanjeevani which is a part of the mission everyone must strive for at the current situation and i.e. Greener Earth. Under this initiative, a mass plantation was proposed to be organized by Mobius Foundation which is headed by Pradip Burman. The initiative will take place with NGO SATHI and currently, the target area is Sonepat, Haryana. With this project, 5,000 saplings will be planted around the villages within a time period of a few months from the day of the announcement. Till now the organization has not reported the success of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It's a project initiated by the Mobius Foundation "Sanjeevani" to plant 5000 saplings around the villages of Sonepat and Panipat districts of Haryana.